# overriding methods of ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on a Django project where any time an admin does something in the admin console (CRUD), a set of people gets notified.  I was pointed to three methods on ModelAdmin called log_addition, log_created and log_deleted which save all the necessary info into a special database called "django_admin_log".

I placed the following code into my admin.py:

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def log_addition(self, request, object):
      subject = 'admin test of creation'
      message = 'admin creation detected'
      from_addr = 'no_reply@example.com'
      recipient_list = ('luka@example.com',)
      send_mail(subject, message, from_addr, recipient_list)

      return super(ModelAdmin, self).log_addition( *args, **kwargs )
```

This code however, gets ignored when I create new users.  Many posts actually recommend to create a different class name (MyModelAdmin) and I am not entirely sure why - the point is to override the existing model.  I tried it, but with the same result.  Can anyone point me in the right direction please?  How exactly do you override a method of an existing class and give it some extra functionality?
Thank you!
Luka

EDIT:  I figured it out, it seems that I had to unregister and re-register User for my change to work.

Answer (score 2):

remove the **return** at the end.

If that doesn't work, you can instead put the code in a function called **add_view**:

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_view(self, request):
        ...
        super(ModelAdmin, self).add_view( *args, **kwargs)
```

This function can be overwritten to add functionality to the admin's view. If you look at the admin code:

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L923

you will see that the function you have tried to overwrite is called from within the add_view function so you could equally put the code here

Comment: Actually, I don't want to override add_view, because it specifically uses just one of those three methods, so I'd rather override those methods directly.  As I just found it, I need to to the following:       `admin.site.unregister(  User )
admin.site.register( User, MyModelAdmin )` and then my function kicked in.  However, a strange side-effect kicked in - my admin console lost a bunch of helper stuff like filter view, etc.  The functionality is still intact though.